# Помогите пожалуйста со скриптом

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт

```js
(function() {
  /* Это код отвечающий за клики по кнопкам 
      с увеличением числа.
      Необходимым кнопкам необходимо указать id: plus
      (при редактировании кнопки на вкладке: "действия"
    И указать на странице число оборнутое в спан с 
    определленым id:**<span id="numberPlus">0</span>**
      */
  var btnAll = document.querySelectorAll('.btn[hack-data-id=plus]');
  var number = document.getElementById('numberPlus');
  var n = 339;
  number.innerHTML = localStorage.plusNumber || 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < btnAll.length; i++) {
    btnAll[i].setAttribute('data-click', 'true');
  };
  document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var targ = event.target;
    if (check(targ)) {
      updateNum();
      targ.setAttribute('data-click', 'false');
    } else if (check(targ.parentNode)) {
      updateNum();
      targ.parentNode.setAttribute('data-click', 'false');
    }
  });

  function updateNum() {
    lastZn = +localStorage.plusNumber || 0;
    localStorage.plusNumber = lastZn + n;
    number.innerHTML = localStorage.plusNumber;
  };

  function check(elem) {
    return ~elem.className.search('btn') &&
      elem.getAttribute('hack-data-id') === 'plus' &&
      elem.getAttribute('data-click') === 'true';
  };
}());
```

```html
<p style="text-align: right; line-height: 1;">
  <span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px;">
    <strong>Баланс: <span id="numberPlus">0</span></strong>
  </span>
</p>
```

Как прописать  значение id к кнопке `<span id="numberPlus">0</span>`

**Обновление**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="result"></div>
<button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="20">20</button>
<button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="30">30</button>
<button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="40">40</button>
  <script>
    var result = document.getElementById('result')
    var num = 0;
    function setNumber(e){
      result.innerHTML = num += parseInt(e.value);  
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    #result{
  border:1px solid green;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:10px
}
  </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Как блок где появляется число переместить в другой конец сайта. К примеру кнопка в низу страниц а число появляется в верху.

Comment: так у вас уже есть значение id у кнопки, в чем вопрос?

Comment: Как сделать эту кнопку. Этот скрипт у меня работал в готовой платформе. А мне нужен целый код html Кнопка с этим id

Comment: не совсем понятно, что вам надо сделать. Если получить по id то var btn = document.getElementById('numberPlus'). Если изменить атрибут, то document.getElementById('numberPlus').id = 'youNewId''

Comment: если вам надо склонировать объект (создать копию DOM) 
var itm = document.getElementById("numberPlus");
var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
document.getElementById("ИД_блока_в_который_вставить_кнопку").appendChild(cln);

Comment: Смотрите вот скрипт